# What are the legitimate reasons to call MappedByteBuffer.force()?

Tags: java, memory, io, real-time, nio

I imagine two, but I would like to confirm if I am making sense here:

1) JVM exiting on an uncaught exception => probably wrong here since somehow the exiting JVM will do that for me, but it would not hurt to be safe and do it yourself inside a ShutdownHook.

2) If I have to "roll" the ByteBuffer, meaning it will go over capacity and I need a new one => I am thinking about calling force() on the one that's getting full, then discard it, then create a new one starting in the end of the file.

The *ideal* solution would be to have a ByteBuffer that would NEVER go over capacity, but I want to check for this scenario and roll the byte buffer.

So do you think I should call force() in the situations above? Can I just discard the ByteBuffer and open a new one using file.length() without calling force() on the previous one?

Here is my code for my **flush** method:

```
        if (isMemoryMapped) {

            // first test if we are approaching the limit...
            int cap = buffer.capacity();
            int pos = buffer.position();
            float usage = (float) pos / cap;

            if (usage >= Log.getMappedBufferThreshold()) {
                // roll our buffer
                MappedByteBuffer mappedBuffer = (MappedByteBuffer) buffer;
                mappedBuffer.force();
                this.buffer = this.createMappedByteBuffer(outputFile, getMappedBufferSize());
            }

            // Then do NOTHING since this is a memory mapped buffer...

        }
```

Comment: The first scenario that comes to mind: If you were writing some kind of server, and you wanted logging, then ideally the log would be flushed to disk periodically so if the server crashes the log data is not lost.

Comment: @Corbin That sounds reasonable but may actually be wrong. My impression is that Memory Mapped Files are "magically" sent to disk by the OS and you do NOT have to flush it. The OS manages that for you somehow. Otherwise it would be no different than regular files.

Comment: No, it is still buffered.  "Forces any changes made to this buffer's content to be written to the storage device containing the mapped file."

Comment: @Corbin But like Stephen said below the ONLY LEGITIMATE reason is to protect yourself against a catastrophic failure OR if you are need to make sure (commit) your changes to disk IMMEDIATELY. I am removing force from by code above.

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but I believe it buffers like normal.  That's actually a good thing because it means you can overwrite things and they will only be over written in memory, not on disk.  I think the case of periodically flushing logs would still hold, though I'm not very familiar with the buffering model of memory mapping in Java, so perhaps it flushes the buffer a lot more often than I suspect.

Comment: @JohnPristine - I didn't say that.  I did not say that my reasons were the ONLY legitimate reasons.

Comment: @Stephen You edited your answer. Unfortunately stackoverflow won't let me edit my comment anymore. :(

Comment: @JohnPristine - my uneditted answer didn't say that either.  If you don't believe me, look at the history.  You may think that's what I said, but my words don't say that, and I never intended them to be read that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the legitimate reasons to call MappedByteBuffer.force()?

Any time that you need the data to be flushed to disk NOW, rather than waiting until the buffer is unmapped or the application exits.

For example, the "commit" operation in a transactional database implemented using MappedByteBuffers would require you to ensure that the committed data gets written to the disc immediately.

[[ **UPDATE**

Having (re-)read the javadocs for MappedByteBuffer and FileChannel, my conclusion is that it is **prudent** to call `force()` on application shutdown too ... assuming that you want the updates to be flushed.  As far as I can tell, the spec provides no guarantees that data will be flushed apart from in the context of a `force()` call.

**END** ]]

> My impression is that Memory Mapped Files are "magically" sent to disk by the OS and you do NOT have to flush it.

That's not correct.  If the JVM dies catastrophically (or is `kill -9` 'ed) then there is no guarantee that mapped buffers will be flushed.  It is even more uncertainty if the operating system itself dies.

The `force()` operation is for when you need certainty.  If it succeeds, you are guaranteed that your changes are on disc.

Your examples may be legitimate, or not depending on the details of the application.  For instance, doing a `force()` in shutdown hook sounds a bit dangerous.  If the application is shutting down because it has detected an internal error, then flushing the buffer could actually do more harm ... depending on how well you've designed your memory mapped data structures.

Comment: Thanks. So in my code above it is not really necessary because 1) I don't have urgency. 2) I don't want to protect myself against catastrophic failure (assuming that does NOT include uncaught exception)

Comment: @JohnPristine - before you decide that you don't need to `force`, you need to read what the javadocs say about when and how changes to a buffer get flushed to disk.  Then code to what the specification says.  If the specification says nothing, then it is prudent to assume the worst.

Comment: I tested on Linux and Mac. Force is NOT necessary (of course unless what you said above is required by the application). You can just discard the previous MappedByteBuffer, create a new one and continue. The problem of calling force() is that has a big performance impact. It looks like the OS is smart enough to even tell you the correct file length (through File.length()) without a force.

Comment: @JohnPristine I'm not sure if you understand the buffering correctly. When all goes well, calling force is not necessary.  There's a reason it's called *force* after all.

Comment: @StephenC I don't think you can conclude that MappedByteBuffers are never written before application shutdown unless you call force(), which seems to be an implication of what you've said above. If you don't use PRIVATE mode I think you are entitled to expect that data changes will occur on the disk in a reasonably timely way, just like normal writes would be: asynchronously but timely. However I certainly agree that force() is required if you are trying to implement transactional behaviour.

Comment: @EJP - Again, you are making the same mistake as JohnPristine.  I did not conclude that.  What I said was that the spec doesn't say anything on this subject, and that it would be **PRUDENT** not to make assumptions.  My implication is that **we don't know for sure what will happen** ... without testing the behavior or reading the code on each platform of interest.

Comment: @StephenC With respect, the first sentence of your answer assumes exactly that. I agree that it isn't specified any tighter, but the facility would have no practical use in read/write situations if it did no writes until the application exited. It's clearly designed to map into a virtual memory implementation, and all the ones I have ever encountered do timely writes.